# How do I access a local Windows directory as a network drive

Tags: windows, network-shares

At work the software I am helping develop uses network shares, something like `\\store.dev\pics\`. I am setting up the software at home (thanks, snowpocalypse!). I have everything running except for these shares. Is there any way I can access a Windows directory as a network share? So I would like to access `D:\dev\picStore` as `\\store.dev\pics\`

Note that I am using WinXP.

Thanks!  Bill

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared folder, you can actually get to it with shared permissions just like you can from another computer. For example:

If you have a computer named "Bob" and a share named "Builder", you can get to it from the network as "\Bob\Builder", correct? Same thing holds true locally. It's a great way to test if shared permissions work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Duall, but that won't work for my use. That means I have to change the name of my machine to Bob. Also, if I also need \Dora\Explorer (and I do need multiple shares), I need to choose one and suffer without the others. Is there any other solution? Maybe a third party tool?

Comment: So, for your example, the computer is not named "store.dev"? If you have the capability to, you can edit DNS. Let's say you have "Terminator" as the computer, since it's wholly unrelated to our children's-show-related folder names. You could set a CNAME for your Terminator computer to each name you need, e.g. "Dora", "Bob", and "Blues". Then you can just give your shares names of "Explorer", "Builder", and "Clues". Then if you try and access it, it will redirect to your computer. However this would require a server. Standalone, I would use static IP and edit your host file. Should work.

Comment: @Duall: Actually, if the OP is only looking to get at his local machine by name, and it's not store.dev, he could use the hosts file and make the entry point to 127.0.0.1.  No DNS or Static IP necessary.  And he should be able to use 1 entry for each server he needs to simulate.  He will have to share the folders out correctly though.

Comment: Also, if there's no password on the account being used, a security policy will need changed in order for this to work at all.  In `Local Security Policy`, it's `Local Policies -> Security Options -> Accounts: Limit local use of blank passwords to console logon only`.  This will need to be disabled.  Even though it's only connecting to itself, Windows will see it as a "network" connection, not a console logon.  Alternatively, the OP could just put a password on his or her account.

Comment: @afrazier, in hindsight you're right. He only needs to get on the local machine, so the loopback ip would be easiest and most efficient. Though I stand by my answer if he needs to do it in a multi-computer environment.

Comment: Thanks to both Duall and afrazier. I think I am close but not quite there. Here is my current situation:

Comment: Sorry, hit the return too quick. I think I am close but not quite there. Here is my current situation: -my computer name is 'basement1', -I do not have a DNS server at home, -I do use static IP at home, -I added this line to my hosts file: '127.0.0.1   store.dev', -I added a share called 'pics', -I disabled the security setting afrazier recommended, -my login account does have a password on it. When I try to connect to '\\store.dev\pics' I get a dialog box asking for a password. I try both nothing and my account password, but it doesn't like either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you be entering the user name wrong possibly?

Comment: Ahh, you are correct Duall. The user name field is not editable, however it is set to 'Guest'. Why is it defaulting to Guest? How do I set it to the user who is currently logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

1. Start the registry editor (regedt32.exe)
2. Move to HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
3. From the Edit menu select "Add Value"
4. Set the type to REG_SZ is you want one extra name or REG_MULTI_SZ if you want more than one and enter a name of OptionalNames. Click OK
5. You will then be prompted for a value. Enter the other name (or names if type REG_MULTI_SZ, one on each line) you want it to be known as and click OK.
6. Close the registry editor
7. Reboot the machine
8. There may be a WINS resolution problem. The entries for the additional NetBIOS names will have been dynamically added to the WINS database complete with IP number. However, a "real" server machine in the WINS dbase normally has three WINS entries, 00h, 03h and 20h. Your aliases may only have one, 03h. Therefore you may need to add static entries for the additional NetBIOS names, which created all three entries. You should now be able to ping by NetBIOS name.

From http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/netbios/how-can-i-define-multiple-netbios-names-for-a-machine-.aspx